# Apply param with the translate service and array of strings

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-translate, ionic5

This is [from the doc](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive):

```
translate.get('HELLO', {value: 'world'}).subscribe((res: string) => {
    console.log(res);
    //=> 'hello world'
});
```

How can I apply with the array like so?

```
 setPayPal(): void {
    this.translateService.get(['Client.Pay-With-PayPal', 'Client.Please-Click-And-Make-The-Payment',
     ]).subscribe(res => {
        this.payPal = {
          title: res['Client.Pay-With-PayPal'],
          payPalUrl: environment.payPalUrl,
          description: res['Client.Please-Click-And-Make-The-Payment'] 
        };
      });
  }
```

I can get that value like so: `value: environment.parcelDeliveryCost`

gr.json

```
"Please-Click-And-Make-The-Payment":"Bitte anklicken und die Bezahlung von {{value}} vornehmen",
```

So my question here is how to apply it with the array?

Comment: I don't know if that's built in, but can't you do it yourself with `forkJoin`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh.. This is a great tip. I'll try that and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, it is working perfectly fine. Would you like to put it as an answer? This is the `gist`: https://gist.github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/a1d978e3cb8f9f04c53b17facf9ec2cb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's Answer**

```
setPayPal(): void {

    forkJoin([this.translateService.get(['Client.Pay-With-PayPal', 'Client.Pay-Now']),
    this.translateService.get('Client.Please-Click-And-Make-The-Payment', { value: environment.parcelDeliveryCost })])
      .subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
        this.payPal = {
          title: res1['Client.Pay-With-PayPal'],
          payPalUrl: environment.payPalUrl,
          description: res2,
          parentButtonText: res1['Client.Pay-With-PayPal'],
          childButtonText: res1['Client.Pay-Now'],
        };
      });
  }
```

**Original Answer**

You could trigger multiple observables using RxJS `forkJoin`, `combineLatest` or `zip` methods based on the nature of observables and requirement. Try the following

```js
forkJoin({
  'Client.Pay-With-PayPal': this.translateService.get('Client.Pay-With-PayPal'),
  'Client.Please-Click-And-Make-The-Payment': this.translateService.get('Client.Please-Click-And-Make-The-Payment')
}).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.payPal = {
      title: response['Client.Pay-With-PayPal'],
      payPalUrl: environment.payPalUrl,
      description: response['Client.Please-Click-And-Make-The-Payment'] 
    };
  },
  error => {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

Note that `forkJoin` only emits when all the observables complete. If they are persistent observables and you wish to use only the first emitted values, you could use `combineLatest` method and pipe in a `take(1)` operator.

One more thing, while `forkJoin` has an overload to accept plain objects as arguments (like shown above), the `combineLatest` and `zip` do not have them. The arguments should be an array.

Comment: Yes, `forkJoin` works. But should I unsubscribe it? I know there is no need to unsubscribe the plain `translateService.get()` Subscription. But what about `forkJoin`?

Comment: It is always better to unsubscribe from the observables in Angular, including the ones from HttpClient. There is always a probability where the router is redirected to another component while the subscription is still in progress. In that case it might be left open.

Comment: Yes, but here it is different. Please see here: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/796#issuecomment-401114459

Comment: Then in this case unsubscription isn't required. `forkJoin` doesn't modify the observables like operators that return a new modified observable. It is still the source observable that is directly subscribed to.